# Iframe not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, iframe

Please take a look at my website [inpages.nl](http://inpages.nl/)

If you go to the word "weer" and click it an iframe will show up containing some sort of weather map. The problem is that it is not showing the weathermap in Firefox. I googled for it and as it seems Firefox does has issues showing iframes. However the wierd thing is that it DOES show the iframe, its just a the (dynamic) weather chart which is not showing. If I isolate the iframe from the click event and show it on page load than everything seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After inspecting your html in firefox and chrome, it looks like there is a problem, not in your script but in the page you are opening in the iframe (but don't worry, I found a possible workaround).

**First, this is the problem**: Use Chrome's inspector and Firefox's firebug and you will see that the iframe is pointing to 
`http://www.weeronline.nl/Go/ExternalWidgetsNew/RainAnd2DaysCity?gid=4057473&temperatureScale=Celsius&defaultSettings=False`, inside that webpage there is another iframe pointing to `http://www.weeronline.nl/Go/ExternalWidgetsNew/RainWidgetContent?gid=4057473&sizeType=1` (both addresses are the same in both browsers).

Inside that inner iframe there is a div called `radar-container`, and its css has a `.image-rotator-container` selector that has set `display:none;`. In google chrome the div contains an inline style of `display:block` (and a background-image). But in firefox the div it doesn't have the `display:block` (only the background image). So, the problem is that teir scripts are not "showing" the map's div.

**The good news:** it looks like if you reload the iframe "manually" (I did it by adding a fake parameter to the url using firebug: `http://www.weeronline.nl/Go/ExternalWidgetsNew/RainWidgetContent?gid=4057473&sizeType=1&foo`) you can see the map. So, you can let the url of the iframe empty when the page loads, and then (on `$(document).ready()`) you set the url.

Side note: your webpage can't find a `http://inpages.nl/jquery.nicescroll.min.js` and a lot of images from your site. That is not related to your question but you should take a look.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time and effort. It still doesn't work for me, but I accepted your anwser because I now know what is going on. Since it is on the iframe side it is kinda out of my hand. I think I'm going to remove the whole thing and replace it with something else. If you go the the website you will see I added  `$("#widget-frame").attr("src", "http://www.weeronline.nl/Go/ExternalWidgetsNew/RainAnd2DaysCity?gid=4057473&temperatureScale=Celsius&defaultSettings=False");` right after document ready with no luck. Regarding your side note; I know about this, the website is not finished yet:)

Comment: Oke, I just did it on click and it now works. Thanks again very much:)